# Jquery: How do i not select a specific column

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a table, where i have a click event on the tr:

```
<tr id="<%= candidate.AnsogerID %>" class="newCandidatesTableTr">
```

, this click event:

```
$(".newCandidatesTableTr").click(function(e) {
```

works just fine, but in the row i also have a click event on a td:

```
$(".insertCandidate").live("click", (function(e) {
```

and this conflicts eachother. I want to do one thing if the tr is clicked and other when this specific td in the tr is clicked. So how do i in my tr.click() event defined that the event shall not happend when i click the specific td?

Here is the code:

```
// Lists a table with old candidates who migth be the same person as the new candidate
        $(".newCandidatesTableTr").click(function(e) {
            alert(this.id);
            GetCandidateName(this.id);
        });

// Show insert candidate dialog
        $(".insertCandidate").live("click", (function(e) {
            var tempCanName = $(".suggentionCandidatesTableTitle").text();
            var tempCanNameSub = tempCanName.substr(0, tempCanName.length - 1);
            var canName = $(".suggentionCandidateName_" + canID + "").text();
            $("#mergeCandidateDialog").empty();
            $.blockUI({ message: $("#mergeCandidateDialog").append(
                "<div>" + tempCanNameSub + "'s ansøgning vil blive lagt under den eksiterende ansøger " + canName + "'s data.<br /><br /> Ønsker du at fortsætte?<br /><br /></div>" +
                "<div id=\"content\">" +
                "<input type=\"button\" id=\"" + this.id + "\" class=\"insertCandidateYes\" value=\"Ja\" />" +
                "<input type=\"button\" id=\"insertCandidateNo\" value=\"Nej\" /></div>"), css: { cursor: 'default', fontWeight: 'normal', padding: '7px', textAlign: 'left' }
            });
        }));

<% foreach (var candidate in Model.Ansogninger)
        {
             %>
                <tr id="<%= candidate.AnsogerID %>" class="newCandidatesTableTr">
                    <td><div id="candidateID""><label title="<%= candidate.Navn %>"><%= candidate.AnsogerID %></label></div></td>
                    <td><div id="<%= "candidateName_" + candidate.AnsogerID %>" class="candidateNameTD"><%= candidate.Navn %></div></td>
                    <td><div id="candidateEmail"><%= candidate.Email %></div></td>
                    <td><div id="candidateRundeName"><%= Model.RundeName %></div></td>
                    <td id="testTD">
                        <div id="<%= "acceptCandidateButton_" + candidate.AnsogerID %>" class="acceptb">Godkend</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             <%
        } %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case

```
$(".insertCandidate").live("click", (function(e) {
    // do td stuff here
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop propagating event
});
```

will do that for you.

You can see a working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/iyelo/edit)

Comment: i assume you meant to have script tags

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to stop the `tr` click handler from being called by doing `e.stopPropagation()` in the `td` click handler.  If it doesn't, try `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Answer (score 1):

in your td click event you could use `stopPropagation();`
This will make sure no more click events is fired after that one is finished.

**Edit**:
If you're using IE, you might wanna try `window.event.cancelBubble = true;`

Also, what I meant by no more events are fired after it is finished, I meant that no more events will be fired after `stopPropagation()`, and if you placed that inside the td click event, the tr click event shouldn't be fired...

Comment: You wrote that it stops other events from firing AFTER it have finised and that is not what i need. I need the tr clicked to not be fired at all. Thus it should not fire when i click the td event, but it does eventho i use e.stopPropagation();

Any other suggentions?

Answer (score 1):

Several answers here about using `stopPropagation`, which is the direct answer to the question.

I wonder, though, if stepping back a bit might help:  Remember that click events bubble (in fact, that's what you're running into), and so I wonder if you may want to *not* hook the click event on the row or cell at all, but instead on the *table*. (This is sometimes called event delegation.) In the table's `click` handler, you can find out what element was actually clicked (row, cell, etc.). I don't know the jQuery syntax for doing that, but Prototype provides [`Event#findElement`](http://prototypejs.org/api/event/findElement) for this purpose and I'm sure that jQuery has something similar; if not, it's easy enough to write it up starting from the event's `target` property and using jQuery's powerful DOM traversing tools.

Having one handler rather than dozens or hundreds is more memory-efficient, and frequently simpler to code as well.

Comment: I've used this method a number of times and have to agree with T.J. the other nice benefit is that such a method will automatically recognize any new rows you add to the table via AJAX, whereas you'd have to reattach these click events to any rows added that way using another method.

Comment: no, you wouldn't have to re-attach the click events. Notice he's using the jQuery `live()` method? That means he's dealing with a live HTML collection.